# How to build a DataBase Miner?

Tags: database

Has everybody here ever built a DB Miner?

If you have ever built a DB Miner then can
you give some sort of knowledge of how to build
one or suggest me some books that i should read 
in preparing for it.

Cause i'm trying to build a DB Miner but i stuck
in what to begin.

Thank you !

Comment: what do you mean by a DB miner? is it like MIS reporting system and database analysis?

Comment: DB Miner is a kind of system that support us in mining database such as transaction database, data cube ..etc. It can help us to discover some rules from DB, for example association rules and so on.

Comment: Do you have an specific language to develop your app/miner?

Comment: Read [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-datamineparsephp/index.html) basic practical php code from IBM website.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it would be terrible advice if I tell you not to build your own? It has to be a hellishly complex subject if you're attempting to build something that works on many data sets.

Here's a demo of how to do some data mining on the StackOverflow database using some free Excel plug-in from Microsoft:
http://sqlserverpedia.com/blog/sql-server-tutorial/data-mining-the-stackoverflow-database/

Comment: Thank you, i get it. You are right, building my own Database Miner is really hard and there are a lot of complex works need to be done.

BTW: I wish i can vote for you but my reputation is too low, so maybe another time.
Thank you.

Comment: Good plug-in but requires SQL Server (licensed), also you can download  a trial version but requires some Gigabytes to install and work properly.

Answer (score 0):

[Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471462616) has lots of stuff.  Pick one.  I chose this because I guessed that you'd like it to be SQL Server-specific.

Comment: Thank you, but it's to general. Can you tell me exactly what that "one" is ? Cause Amazon is a huge book store. BTW, you are right, i'm working mostly with SQL Server

Comment: The Amazon link is to a specific SQL Server based book that might help you with this question.